# C# Capture Video Stream From Window

Tags: c#, video-capture

I am trying to create a window preview (much like Windows7 'peek' feature) for a PC game. I'd like to capture the realtime game video output to the game window and create a mini preview in a panel.

Any hints on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't this be posted at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to research 'Hooking'.

Essentially you need to 'hook' whats being rendered to the back buffer before it gets swapped to the  screen.

See the following article for hooking into the back buffer in directx:
http://spazzarama.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/screen-capture-with-direct3d-api-hooks/

It's not exactly an easy process!